How to handle dark / light mode control when design already has contrasting pages
Let’s say your app or website is predominantly a “light UI” but has some pages that have been intentionally designed with a “dark UI” to contrast the main palette.
And now you want to introduce a light/dark mode user control toggle.
Clearly when the user toggles to dark mode, the main UI would adjust to dark. But how would you handle the pages that already have a dark UI by default?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From what you've described so far, there doesn't seem to be an explicit reason why the intentionally dark UI should be any different in the 'new' dark UI mode. Can you clarify the reason or purpose why it contrasts the default/light UI in the first place? That would help understanding the problem.

Hi @JosvanWeesel - these areas of the app are for an adjascent “mode” of the app and are triggered in specific physical contexts. Spotify “car mode” or Audible “car mode” would be similar context-specific mode examples. They were designed with a contrasting UI palette to differentiate them from the primary mode of the app. Hope that clarifies

@smhdgs Are the "pages that have been intentionally designed with a dark UI" supposed to have light mode?

If the question is to differentiate between normal dark mode and special dark modes, why not just play with the background color. May be tint the whole screen blue or green like night-vision goggles do.

As many have asked in the comments, the 'need' is not clear. Also, please add images of the examples cited - spotify normal dark mode vs. spotify car mode.

The use of light and dark mode works better in helping improve readability and clarity of screen content under different conditions, rather than to highlight different modes (in fact it already indicates that the user or device is operating under different environmental conditions).
You can create problems in design by adding features or details that doesn't apply across the board (i.e. as part of a design system), because then it becomes difficult to maintain consistency and simplicity once you run into situations exactly as you have described above. Rather than trying to create some arbitrary rule to address the scenario, it is better to fix the problem by designing the light and dark mode into the overall design system and go from there.
This will also have the added benefit of allowing you to accommodate more than one mode, rather than being locked into two modes only.
